# Button position changes when I expand the window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a webpage where the top division is an image with a transparent button on it.The problem is that each time I minimize the window, the button changes position. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

```
<html lang=="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Deut65</title>
  <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<ul id="nav">
  <img id="logo" src="logo.png"></img>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#editor">Editor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>


   <div id="image-div">
      <img id="top-image"src="fotoDeut65.jpeg">
      <button id="image-button">Button</button>
   </div>


<style>


 #image-div{ 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
 }

#top-image{
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

#image-button{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
   top: 191px;
    left: 420px;
    right: -420px;
    bottom: -191px;
}
</style>




<!--until here-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sems to work? https://jsfiddle.net/snn90fm5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `position:absolute;` if you want button float on img
The style above has misstakes, try the below to comprehensive:

```
<style>
 #image-div{ background:lightblue;
 }

#top-image{
 width:100px;height:100px;
}

#image-button{background:red;    
 position: absolute;
 left:0;
 width:100px;height:100px; 
}
</style>
```